# Proving monad option with None?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

Given this option monad:

```
module OptMonad = 
  struct
    type 'a t = 'a option
    let return v = Some v
    let bind m f = 
      match m with
      | Some v -> f v (***)
      | None -> None
    let (>>=) = bind (* as always *)
  end
```

I want to prove these two laws:
`Law 1:  (return x) >>= f ⇔ f x` and
`Law 2:  m >>= return ⇔ m`

- For Law 1: `return x = Some x, so: Some x >>= f ⇔ f x`
- For Law 2: `Case 1: m = Some x, so: Some x >>= return ⇔ Some x = m, Case 2: m = None, so: None >>= return ⇔ None = m`

But for Law 1, we don't have to consider the `None` case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will `OptMonad.return` ever yield `None`?

No.